# pm2 Error: EMFILE, too many open files

Tags: node.js, microservices, pm2

---

I am using PM2 to manage our Node.js based micro services platform. We wanted a dashboard from where we can see the micro services status e.g. if any service is taking too much CPU or memory and for that I used PM2's api and wrote the following piece of code.

```
function getMicroService(){
    pm2.connect(function(err) {
        if(!err){
            // Get all processes running
            logger.info('core_module','Connecting to PM2 Daemon for Micro Services List');
            var dataArr = {};
            var microServices = [];
            var counter = 0;
            var curDateTime = helperLib.getDateTimeISO();
            pm2.list(function(err, process_list) {
                if(process_list.length > 0){
                    process_list.forEach(function(process){
                        delete process.pm2_env;
                        process.lastChecked = curDateTime;
                        microServices.push(process);
                        counter++;
                    })
                }
                if(counter == process_list.length){
                    dataArr.event = 'microServices';
                    dataArr.data = microServices;
                    publishStats(dataArr);
                }
            });
        }else{
            logger.error('core_module','on Line 245: '+err)
        }
    })  
}
```

The above function is called every 15 seconds and it displays data on the Dashboard. But I noticed that this service started taking too much CPU over 100% and PM2 whole Daemon service went offline and stopped responding. Couldn't issue any command e.g. pm2 stop all etc. I had to manually kill the processes and then start the service again. The error I extracted from the Log file is

```
{"message":"core_module Threw Exception: ","stack":"Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/root/.pm2/pm2.log'\n    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)\n    at module.exports.Client.launchDaemon (/etc/node/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:207:14)\n    at /etc/node/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:102:10\n    at /etc/node/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:294:14\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)","errno":-24,"code":"EMFILE","syscall":"open","path":"/root/.pm2/pm2.log","__error_callsites":[{},{},{},{},{},{}],"level":"error","timestamp":"2017-10-20T00:49:26.826Z"}
```

Could anyone please help out if the above code is right. Calling it every 15 seconds is a good approach or how can I optimize it. Should I call pm2.disconnect() at the end of the function.

Please advise.

Regards
Habib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `pm.disconnect()` at the end, otherwise you'll end up leaving all the created connections open. It says in the [pm2 api documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/):

`If your script does not exit by itself, make sure you called pm2.disconnect() at the end.`